# Error Loading UserControl

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, user-controls

I have created a new View in my WPF Application.
When I attempt to load the View, I receive the following errors:

"An unhandled excetion of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
"Additional Information: Input string was not in a correct format"
"When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object."

I know it has something to do with the LINQ to SQL query in my ViewModel, because when I comment it out, everything works; however, there are no DateTime fields in my Model.

As you can see below the model is made of of strings, int, and bool values.

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Model

```
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> employeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string parentBranch { get; set; }
    public string branch { get; set; }
    public bool ATS { get; set; }
    public bool website { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
    public bool HR { get; set; }
    public string timesheet { get; set; }
    public string debug { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<UserControl x:Class="Craig_Tools.ApplicationTrackingSystem.Views.Security"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Craig_Tools.ApplicationTrackingSystem.userControls.datagrids"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <dg:dg_security />
    </ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
public partial class SecurityViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SecurityViewModel()
    {
        LoadSecurity();
    }

     public void LoadSecurity()
    {
        using (JobSeekersEntities db = new JobSeekersEntities())
        {
            var q = (from s in db.securities
                     select s).ToList();

            securityList = new ObservableCollection<security>(q);
        }
    }

    //ObservableCollections
    private ObservableCollection<security> securityList;
    public ObservableCollection<security> SecurityList
    {
        get { return securityList; }
        set
        {
            securityList = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SecurityList");
        }
    }
    //Constructors
    private int selectedSecurity;
    public int SelectedSecurity
    {
        get { return selectedSecurity; }
        set
        {
            { selectedSecurity = value; }
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedSecurity");
        }
    }
    //Commands

}
```

Comment: Do your JobSeekersEntities contain any DateTime fields/properties?

Comment: @Joe Yes, in other tables.  In the security table, no.

Comment: I figured it out.  In my dg_security.xaml usercontrol for the datagrid I forgot   the {Binding } on the SelectedValue of ID, which was causing it to not load correctly.

Comment: Ah, completely overlooked you were displaying a completely separate user control. This one had me stumped.